# Problem with LoF due to \captionof position

Tags: tcolorbox

I used `minipage` to create subfigures within `tcolorbox` of which underneath "OneCol" command as shown in picture. Everything works fine, box is breakable, I'm be able to put text and pictures in the box without any problems except LoF is not correct. As you can see, when I have `\captionof{}` at the bottom of picture (Problem 0.2), subfigure of Figure 0.2 was moved to Figure 0.1 in the List of Figures. When I place `\captionof{}` on top of picture (Problem 0.3), List of Figures 0.3 is in correct order. I personally prefer to have `\captionof` underneath the picture than on top of picture.

1. How to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{adjmulticol}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx,kantlipsum,multicol}
\usepackage[papersize={21cm,23cm},top=1.8cm, bottom=2cm, outer=7cm, inner=2cm, heightrounded, marginparwidth=5.0cm, marginparsep=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\definecolor{LightOcean}{RGB}{81, 147, 229 }
\definecolor{DeepOcean}{RGB}{51, 131, 229}

%CREATE NEW COMMAND for one columns
\newenvironment{OneCol}{\normalsize
    \begin{adjmulticols}{1}{0cm}{-5.5cm}}{\end{adjmulticols}}

%Define framed box for example problem
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{examplebox}[2][]{breakable,colback=LightOcean!10, colframe=DeepOcean,fonttitle=\bfseries, title=\Large{\textbf{Problem.}}~\thetcbcounter \ : #2,#1}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
{\Large\bfseries}
{}
{0pt}
{\hspace{-0cm}% Move into margin
    \tikz[overlay] \shade[left color=black!20, right color=white] (0,-1ex) rectangle (\dimexpr\textwidth+5.5cm,1.2em);% Set background shaded rectangle
    \makebox[2em][l]{\thesection}#1}% Set number + title

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{Section 1}
\vspace{0cm}
\begin{OneCol}  
        \begin{examplebox}[label={myautocounter}]{}
        \kant[1]
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}
            \captionof{figure}{The caption1}
        \end{center}
    \end{examplebox}    
\end{OneCol}    

\newpage
\section{Section 2}
\begin{OneCol}
\begin{examplebox}[label={myautocounter}]{Reaction}
    \begin{center}%
        \begin{minipage}{0.24\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a.jpg}%
            \captionof{subfigure}{A}\label{example-image-a.jpg}%
        \end{minipage}
        \hfill
        \begin{minipage}{.24\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b.jpg}%
            \captionof{subfigure}{B}\label{example-image-b.jpg}%
        \end{minipage}
        \hfill
        \begin{minipage}{.24\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c.jpg}%
            \captionof{subfigure}{C}\label{example-image-c.jpg}%
        \end{minipage}  
        \vspace{-2mm}
        \captionof{figure}{The first 3 letters of alphabet.}
    \end{center}
\end{examplebox}
\end{OneCol}

\section{Section 3}
\begin{OneCol}
    \begin{examplebox}[label={myautocounter}]{Reaction}
        \begin{center}%
            \captionof{figure}{The first 3 letters of alphabet.}
            \vspace{2mm}
            \begin{minipage}{0.24\linewidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a.jpg}%
                \captionof{subfigure}{A}\label{example-image-a.jpg}%
            \end{minipage}
            \hfill
            \begin{minipage}{.24\linewidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b.jpg}%
                \captionof{subfigure}{B}\label{example-image-b.jpg}%
            \end{minipage}
            \hfill
            \begin{minipage}{.24\linewidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c.jpg}%
                \captionof{subfigure}{C}\label{example-image-c.jpg}%
            \end{minipage}
        \end{center}
    \end{examplebox}
\end{OneCol}

\end{document}
```

[image: page1]

[image: page2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work with the `\subcaption` command, there one need to fiddle with `\ContinuedFloat` and `\captionlistentry`. But if you use the  `subfigure` environment it works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{list}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures


\begin{figure}[h!]
        \begin{subfigure}{0.24\linewidth}
            \caption{A}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{0.24\linewidth}
            \caption{B}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{0.24\linewidth}
            \caption{C}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{The first 3 letters of alphabet.}
\end{figure}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\captionsetup{type=figure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.24\linewidth}
            \caption{A}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{0.24\linewidth}
            \caption{B}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{0.24\linewidth}
            \caption{C}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{The first 3 letters of alphabet.}
\end{minipage}


\begin{figure}[h!]
\captionlistentry{The first 3 letters of alphabet}%
        \begin{minipage}{0.24\linewidth}
            \subcaption{A}
        \end{minipage}
        \hfill
        \begin{minipage}{.24\linewidth}
            \subcaption{B}
        \end{minipage}
        \hfill
        \begin{minipage}{.24\linewidth}
            \subcaption{C}
        \end{minipage}

        \ContinuedFloat
        \caption[]{The first 3 letters of alphabet.}
\end{figure}


\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\captionsetup{type=figure}%
\captionlistentry{The first 3 letters of alphabet}%
        \begin{minipage}{0.24\linewidth}
            \subcaption{A}
        \end{minipage}
        \hfill
        \begin{minipage}{.24\linewidth}
            \subcaption{B}
        \end{minipage}
        \hfill
        \begin{minipage}{.24\linewidth}
            %\captionof{subfigure}{C}\label{example-image-c2.jpg}% gives error
            \subcaption{C}
        \end{minipage}

        \ContinuedFloat
        \caption[]{The first 3 letters of alphabet.}
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

[image]

For your example this means (shorten a bit):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{adjmulticol}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx,kantlipsum,multicol}
\usepackage[papersize={21cm,23cm},top=1.8cm, bottom=2cm, outer=7cm, inner=2cm, heightrounded, marginparwidth=5.0cm, marginparsep=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\definecolor{LightOcean}{RGB}{81, 147, 229 }
\definecolor{DeepOcean}{RGB}{51, 131, 229}

%CREATE NEW COMMAND for one columns
\newenvironment{OneCol}{\normalsize
    \begin{adjmulticols}{1}{0cm}{-5.5cm}}{\end{adjmulticols}}

%Define framed box for example problem
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{examplebox}[2][]{breakable,colback=LightOcean!10, colframe=DeepOcean,fonttitle=\bfseries, title=\Large{\textbf{Problem.}}~\thetcbcounter \ : #2,#1}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{list}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures


\section{Section 2}
\begin{OneCol}
\begin{examplebox}[label={myautocounter}]{Reaction}
    \begin{center}%
    \captionsetup{type=figure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.24\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a.jpg}%
            \subcaption{A}\label{example-image-a.jpg}%
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{0.24\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b.jpg}%
            \subcaption{B}\label{example-image-b.jpg}%
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{0.24\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c.jpg}%
            \subcaption{C}\label{example-image-c.jpg}%
        \end{subfigure}
        \vspace{-2mm}

        \caption{The first 3 letters of alphabet.}
    \end{center}
\end{examplebox}
\end{OneCol}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To Fischer: Thank you so much for your help. I tried \subfigure at the beginning. At that moment, I put\usepackage{subfig} and found out that someone said subfig package is incompatible with scrbook. So, I changed to use minipage instead. Just curiosity, Which package provide us subfigure command?.

Comment: My examples compiles so it should be clear which packages you need ... And it is the subfigure *environment* not a command.

Comment: Don't put two rather unrelated questions in one question, create a new one.

Comment: Fischer: OK. I'll remove and create another one.

Comment: Since I'm new, if I accepted your answer, should I close this question?. If yes, how to close it?.

Comment: Why should you close it? The question and the answer are valid. Leave it as it is now, that's fine so.